# dcc.store value not updating when i access the database in Python Dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

i have been trying to create a dashboard using Python Dash. The dashboard tries to access the database after every 5 seconds and tries to update the graph. After getting the values from the db for the first time, I try to update the store with the values of the dataframe that are in the format.

| Date           | Count |

| -----          | ------ |

| 01-01-2022     | 55  |

| 02-01-2022     | 45  |

I try to save the count as a list [55, 45]. Then after every 5 seconds, i again fetch the data and extend the array with the new values like [55 , 45 , 65 , 30 ....]. However, the dcc.store doesn't save the value and comes as the initial value of the dcc.store after every single update.

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output, State
import plotly.express as px
import dash
import time
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
import asyncio
from bson import ObjectId
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

from get_data import init


# DASH APP
app = Dash(__name__)

# Interval in milliseconds
interval = 5000

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[ html.H1(children="Time Series Reach Analysis"), 
               html.P(children="Time Series Dataset from August 2021 to October 2022"),
               html.Div(id="timeseries-graph", children=[]),
               html.Div(id="interval-counter", children=[]),
               dcc.Store(id='df-storage', data=[], storage_type="memory"),
               dcc.Interval(id='interval-time', interval=interval, n_intervals=0)
                ],
    style={ "text-align" : "center" } 
)

@app.callback(
    # Returned Values
    Output("df-storage", "data"),
    Output("interval-counter", "children"),
    
    # Parameters
    Input("interval-time", "n_intervals"),
    State("df-storage", "data")
)
def refresh_graph(n_intervals, data):
    storage_value = []
    if n_intervals == 0:
        fetched_df = init()   

        print("0 - Df = ", fetched_df)

        data.extend(fetched_df["_id"].tolist())

        print(f"00 - Values for n_intervals-{n_intervals} and data-{data}")

        return data , f"Intervals : {n_intervals}"
        
    else:
        fetched_df = init()    

        data.extend(fetched_df["_id"].tolist())
    
        return  data , f"Intervals : {n_intervals}"

@app.callback( 
    Output("timeseries-graph", "children"),  
    Input("df-storage", "data"),
)
def create_graph(data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["_id"])
    fig = px.line( df, y="_id", x=df.index.tolist() )
    return dcc.Graph(figure=fig)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

init() function simply fetches the data from mongodb and converts it into the dataframe of timestamp and count. However, when I try to do the same thing without fetching the data from the database, then the same code behaves exactly as it should.

I tried the same code without fetching the data using random.random() function and after every 5 second interval add new value to the "data" list. Then it worked as one would expect. I would be thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer.

The reason why it wasn't working properly with the database call was, The database call was taking longer than my interval.

So Dash would update the n_interval count when the 5 seconds interval passes. Resulting in kicking another call, that would lead to another database call, while the previous db call is still in the hanging.

I solved the issue by making a longer interval time. That would help in finishing the database call before the next interval update happens.